# Masking out the video background in Sony Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro, chromakey

I have a video and I need to mask out the background for it.

[image: Muppet Show number]
<sup>A screenshot from the original video, credits to The Muppets Studio</sup>

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N_tupPBtWQ) has been shot with a **still camera** on a steady background. 
My goal is to mask out the background (e.g., everything not related to moving objects).
I don't have the original sources, of course.
It is also hard to recreate the background (I mean, to precisely match colors).

My approach, in theory, is the following:

1. Collect a series of screenshots where different parts of background are visible (when objects move away);
2. Glue those parts into a background image *(see image below for a partial result)*;
3. Place the background into a layer and compute the **color difference** between the original video and the background;
4. Build a set of pixels for which:

   - the difference is **nearly zero** (within a certain color threshold occurring due to rounding/compression problems);
   - **and** within a certain minimal area (so that individual pixels did not occasionally appear);
5. Wrap those pixels into a key mask.

Still, I'm stuck with *building a proper structure of layers* within Sony Vegas to accomplish my goal.

**How this can be done?**

[image: background]
<sup>My backround attempt</sup>

My environment is:

- Sony Vegas 12.0/x64, I'm not considering another software;
- Basic set of plugins/filters, but I will also appreciate references to 3rd-party plugins, even the commercial ones;
- Still, I would prefer a "clean" approach based on masking.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You seem to be heading down the right track, you might also have some luck with blending options, but I imagine you will need some kind of key that you can feed from a hidden track.  I don't have Vegas though, so I can't really help you with specific details other than to say you seem to be heading in the right direction and wish you the best.

Answer (score -2):

chroma key choose a colour*drag) then take eye dropper and select background in the preview window

Comment: The OP's question shows that they have already tried simplistic approaches such as the one you suggest, and they are looking for more powerful solutions.  To prove you have a great answer, test the technique you propose, show the max, and let that be the proof that you have offered the correct answer.